# Check if a table contains a row with a specific column value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, exists

In T-SQL syntax, how could I check to see if a table has a row with a a column matching a particular value? I am using SQL Server 2012 and am completely new to it.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what do you mean with member of a particular column?

Comment: What is your definition of an "entry?" [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What do you mean "member"? And what is a "cell"? Is this an Excel sheet?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE [column] = 'column_value')
  -- The value 'column_value' was found in column [column]
```

- [`IF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx)
- [`EXISTS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx)
- [`SELECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx)

Comment: Thank you. You answered perfectly regardless of the fact my question was too vague.